# How show kendo spinner progress when excel file has been downloaded

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I working with kendo ui jquery grid and I want to export data to excel. I would like to show kendo progress spinner while the file is loading and hide it when file is successfully downloaded.

I try it to subscribing to the excelExport event but does not work fine.